# IE11 input width changes when clicked

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So this only happens in IE11 and I cannot figure out what is going on. When I click the input element (basically the focus event) the width of the element changes. I cannot figure out the CSS to fix this. Anyone have any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/JmRby/2/

TABLE

```
<table class="fields" id="EntityDetails_Fields" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="Form">Name:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="Name" id="Name" type="text" value="Memorial Park Group" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Form">NPI:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="NPI" class="TextBox" id="NPI" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Form">Tax ID:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="TaxIDNumber" id="TaxIDNumber" type="text" value="21-21212121" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Form">Medicare:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="MedicareNumber" id="MedicareNumber" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Form">Medicaid:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="MedicaidNumber" id="MedicaidNumber" type="text" value="1234567" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Form">In Use:</td>
        <td><span id="InUse"><input name="InUse$ctl00" id="InUse_ctl00" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS

```
table.fields {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 4px 1%;
}
table.fields .Form, table.fields .fl {
    padding: 2px;
}
table.fields > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 2px 1%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Form, .form, .fl {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 10%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table.fields > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 2px 1%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table.fields input[type='text'], table.fields input[type='password'], table.fields select, .inpt {
    width: 98%;
    border: solid 1px #666;
    color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah mate, here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/3TwKF/

```
input::-ms-clear {
    display:none;
}
```

This is the [culprit (ms-clear)'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx).

Comment: OMG I would have never figured that out, you are a life saver thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
input::-ms-clear 
{
    display:none;
}
```

Changing the text in text box changes the width in IE 11 for following link too. Above solution works for clicking the text. Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3TwKF/20/

Please let me know for any solution