# Changing the text in text box changes the width in IE 11

Tags: html, css

```
input::-ms-clear {
    display:none;
}
```

[IE11 input width changes when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585021/ie11-input-width-changes-when-clicked) -
this solution works for clicking the text box

Changing the text in text box changes the width in IE 11

http://jsfiddle.net/3TwKF/20/

Please let me know for any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like it is a bug in IE you can use margin on the child element.

[How can I work around this IE11 layout bug related to table-cell, text-decoration, and padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251303/how-can-i-work-around-this-ie11-layout-bug-related-to-table-cell-text-decoratio)

So change your percentage based padding to px or em based wil fix the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/3TwKF/22/

```
padding: 2px .5em;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change the css

```
table.fields input[type='text'], table.fields input[type='password'], table.fields select, .inpt 
    width: 98%; to width:100%
```

It will work. All the best